# Count Query with join and union

Tags: linq-to-sql

Hi I want to get the count of this linq query.Im using entity framework with repository pattern.
It is possible to get the result by queryUserWalls.ToList().Count()
which I think is inefficient. 
Can any body help.

```
var queryUserWalls = (from participation in _eventParticipationRepository.GetAll()
                      join eve in _eventRepository.GetAll() on participation.EventId equals eve.Id
                      join userWall in _userWallRepository.GetAll() on participation.EventId equals userWall.EventId
                      where participation.UserId == userId
                      select userWall.Id)

               .Union(from userWall in _userWallRepository.GetAll()
                      select userWall.Id);
```

Comment: Why can't you do a `.Count()` directly? (no `.ToList()`)

Comment: Why can't you call `queryUserWalls.Count()`?

Answer (score 2):

Leave out the `ToList` because it forces query execution. You want to use `Queryable.Count`, not `Enumerable.Count`. Then, it will execute on the server.